# Arena Question-Can more than one match be played at same time in a tournament?

Tags: engines, arena

I am using Arena 3.5.1 version. Is it possible that more than one game can be played parallelly in the tournament? I want to start a Round-Robin tournament between a number of chess engines including stockfish 8, 11 and Lc0 where every engine plays 3 games with every other engine. But it becomes very time consuming as the other games of the same round can't start till the one game is completed. And I'd have to keep my pc on for nearly the whole day.